# MeteorJS: How to set value inside object inside ReactiveDict?

Tags: javascript, meteor

So, I have an object inside a ReactiveDict that I want to update:

```
dataSet = new ReactiveDict('dataSet');
dataSet.set({
 defaultInfo: {
  title: 'Default'
 }
});

updateTitle(title) { 
 // not sure what to put here to update the default title
 dataSet.set({  })
}
```

Thoughts? I'm using ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to create a solution, though not exactly what I had in mind.

I wasn't able to find a way to update the object, only replace it with a new object:

```
  updateTitle(title) {dataSet.set({
   defaultInfo: _.extend(dataSet.get('defaultInfo'), {title: title})
  })}
```

This is using underscoreJS for the _.extend